# IdentityServer4 IsValidReturnUrl returns false for valid url

Tags: identityserver4

I've a test project with this client configuration:

```
public class Clients : IClientStore
    {
        public Task<Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client.webforms",
                ClientName = "WebForms Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = false,

                ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("1234".Sha256())
                    },

                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:9869/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:9869/" },

                AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        CstIdSrvScopeTypes.TestWebForms
                    },
                AllowOfflineAccess = false,
                RequireConsent = false,

                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true
            });
        }
    }
```

When I try to validate it in LoginController I'm getting `false` result (this is from Immediate Window:

```
returnUrl
"http://localhost:9869/signin-oidc"
this.identityServer.IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl)
false
```

Also `this.identityServer.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl)` result is `null`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Having this same issue

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? The `returnUrl` for myself is valid, exists in my data store, and is being sent across the wire from the client.

Comment: As that issue suggests, if you are trying to put your login UI on a different website than the identity server logic, its not yet fully implemented. You could remove the `IsValidReturnUrl` check for now, but I feel other things will eventually break

Comment: I believe @Yes is correct. Don't confuse what happens here with a proper, working redirect that should be happening from an external Client. If that is set up properly, the `GetAuthorizationContextAsync` call will return a non-null result. It looks for URIs that have been configured in IdentityServer4, so URLs such as `~/` or `/Login` may not work (unless configured).

Comment: @DanielL, it's not absolutely clear what you want. The open issue concerns only the UI for IdSrv living on another host than IdSrv. Most of your (and the original) question refers "just a client" which is a totally different story -- when configured properly -- just works according to oidc spec.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you need to add a single RedirectUri when you configur your client that is one of the RedirectUris  that is in the list you have above.

Something like 
#

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = Settings.AuthenticationType,
            Authority = config.Authority,
            RedirectUri = config.RedirectUri
        }
```